# Set Up New Locale On CentOS 6

Tags: centos, locale

I am trying to set up a new locale for my centos server environment. Here is currently shows for `locale -a` command:

```
en_AG
en_AG.utf8
en_AU
en_AU.iso88591
en_AU.utf8
en_BW
en_BW.iso88591
en_BW.utf8
en_CA
en_CA.iso88591
en_CA.utf8
en_DK
en_DK.iso88591
en_DK.utf8
en_GB
en_GB.iso88591
en_GB.iso885915
en_GB.utf8
en_HK
en_HK.iso88591
en_HK.utf8
en_IE
en_IE@euro
en_IE.iso88591
en_IE.iso885915@euro
en_IE.utf8
en_IN
en_IN.utf8
en_NG
en_NG.utf8
en_NZ
en_NZ.iso88591
en_NZ.utf8
en_PH
en_PH.iso88591
en_PH.utf8
en_SG
en_SG.iso88591
en_SG.utf8
en_US
en_US.iso88591
en_US.iso885915
en_US.utf8
en_ZA
en_ZA.iso88591
en_ZA.utf8
en_ZW
en_ZW.iso88591
en_ZW.utf8
```

As you can see, there is no other language locale set up at this moment. I need to add 'de_DE' and 'fr_FR' to add on this list properly. Can anyone please suggest how can I achieve this properly?

Here is what I have done so far:
I followed the instructions on this [link](http://lists.centos.org/pipermail/centos/2013-March/133481.html). With its help, it seems the list is being updated with 'de_DE' locale . But that doesn't doing the work I needed (doesn't working with [gettext](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/)). So, may be I am doing something wrong or there is more to do.

Comment: I tried with the instructions here: http://lists.centos.org/pipermail/centos/2013-March/133481.html . But doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Please [edit](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/117086/edit) your original post and add that information with exactly the command you used and results. Thanks.

Comment: I have edited it, hope this explains better now.